# Weak and Strong Topologies in Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a finite dimensional linear space. Show that the weak and strong topologies on $X$ are the same.

Is it sufficient to show an arbitrary sequence converges in the weak topology iff it converges in the strong topology? Otherwise I will have to produce basis sets for each topologies and argue containment both ways.

Comment: By strong topology do you mean the topology induced by some norm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do weak and original topology coincide?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138548/when-do-weak-and-original-topology-coincide)

Comment: What are the weak and strong topologies on a finite-dimensional linear space?

Comment: @Rob well in the strong toplogy it will be the one obtained from "balls" from the norm. I have to think about the weak topology though. the linked question in the last response shows a solution which I am in the process of studying.

Answer (score 3):

The sequential argument is not really viable, because the weak topology is generally not first-countable (in fact, it is if and only if the normed space is finitely dimensional, and the reason for this begs your question). In more detail, proving that $id: X_{\text{weak}}\to (X,\lVert\bullet\rVert)$ is sequentially continuous does not necessarily prove that it is continuous.

Rather, you should prove that every cubic ball is the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces (which is quite easy to do).

Comment: The question seems to be about finite-dimensional spaces, so your answer doesn't make much sense.

Comment: ya, I suppose I'm only looking at finite dimensions. but this was helpful because I was thinking about whether just showing convergence was enough -- after all, how something converges depends on its topology.

Comment: @RobArthan Of course, if he has a proof of the fact the weak topology on a finite dimensional normed space is first countable without using the fact that said topology is normable, he can use it. My guess is that it begs the question, though.